# Create subsets of an Array using Javascript & Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to create subsets of an Array in a recurring manner. I've an Array in the form of `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. I'd like to create subsets like `[0,1,2]`, `[1,2,3]`,`[2,3,4]`,`[3,4,5]`,`[4,5,6]`,`[5,6,0]`,`[6,0,1]`,`[0,1,2]` and so on. But, its not breaking after `[4,5,6]`.

Here is my code

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('EventController',function EventController($scope) {
   $scope.count = 0;
   var arr = [], subArr = [], currentIndex;  
   for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      arr.push(i)
   }
   $scope.next = function() {
   currentIndex = $scope.count;  
   subArr = [];
   $scope.count++;    
   subArr.push(currentIndex);
   subArr.push(currentIndex+1);
   subArr.push(currentIndex+2);
   if(arr.indexOf(currentIndex+1) == -1) {
     console.log(currentIndex+1,'Element not available');
     $scope.count = 0;
     currentIndex = $scope.count
   }
   console.log(subArr);
 } 
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zvy2c/63/)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are pushing elements before if condition.
1. Move the if block before pushing data to array
2. Change `arr.indexOf(currentIndex+1) == -1` to `arr.indexOf(currentIndex+2) == -1`

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('EventController',function EventController($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  var arr = [], subArr = [], currentIndex;  
  for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  $scope.next = function() {
    currentIndex = $scope.count;
    //console.log(currentIndex);
    subArr = [];
    $scope.count++;

    subArr.push((currentIndex)%arr.length);
    subArr.push((currentIndex+1)%arr.length);
    subArr.push((currentIndex+2)%arr.length);

    console.log(subArr);
  }
});
```

Comment: Amit, partially its right. But not totally, if you see logs, you can see after [4, 5, 6]  [0, 1, 2] is coming, but [5,6,0] should come.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Please check the logs. It should recursively get the subsets

Comment: but your count will always increment. Is that fine?

Comment: Its giving me the correct output. Increment I didn't get you.?

Comment: My event count shows 7,8,9,10 earlier it was ,5,6,0,1 i guess

Comment: I guess that should not be a problem. Actually I'm thinking to implement this scenario in the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/umswXrj8AgpK7T2dP9Pk?p=preview

Comment: It should be fine then

Comment: Can you please check that plunker?

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this:

var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('EventController',function EventController($scope) {
  $scope.count = 0;
  var  subArr = [], currentIndex; 
  $scope.arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $scope.arr.push(i);
  }

  $scope.next = function() {
    currentIndex = $scope.count;
    //console.log(currentIndex);
    subArr = [];
    $scope.count++;    
    subArr.push(currentIndex);  
    if($scope.arr.indexOf(currentIndex) == $scope.arr.length -2) {
    console.log(currentIndex+2,'Element not available');
       subArr.push(currentIndex+1);
        $scope.count = 0;
     subArr.push($scope.arr[0]);

    }
    else if($scope.arr.indexOf(currentIndex) == $scope.arr.length -1) {
    console.log(currentIndex+1,'Element not available');
     subArr.push($scope.arr[0]);
      subArr.push($scope.arr[1]);
      currentIndex = $scope.count;
    }
        else{
    subArr.push(currentIndex+1);
    subArr.push(currentIndex+2);
    }
    console.log(subArr);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below code will help. It is self explanatory.

```
function createSubset (array, subsetSize, subsets){

  var inputArray = array,
  subset,
  subsetCollection = [],
  noOfSubsets = subsets || inputArray.length + 1,
  size = subsetSize,
  current = 0,
  i;

  while (noOfSubsets--) {    
   subset = [];
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    subset.push( inputArray[ (current + i) % inputArray.length] );
   }
   current += 1 ;
   subsetCollection.push(subset);
  }

  return subsetCollection;
}

console.log('Test Case start');
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
result = createSubset(a, 3);
console.log(result);
console.log('Test Case end'); 


console.log('Test Case start');
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
result = createSubset(a, 3, 4);
console.log(result);
console.log('Test Case end');
```